# Angular 7 change detection not triggering even upon calling ChangeDetectorRef.DetectChanges

Tags: angular

I have this code in my Angular 7 application:

In the child component:

```js
@Input() lstBlocks;
```

In the parent component I am passing this a list as:

```html
<block-container [lstBlocks]="lstBlockDtos"></block-container>
```

`lstBlockDtos` is an array which contains arrays. e.g. an array on index 0, 1, 2 etc...

In the parent container I am replacing the content of one of the nested arrays:

```js
const dtosIndex = this.lstBlockDtos.findIndex(bDto => bDto.planDate === planDateFormatted);    
this.lstBlockDtos[dtosIndex] = mblockDtos;
```

...where `mblockDtos` is a new array with more content.

My issue is that change detection is not working on the child when I change the contents of the inner array. I have implemented the `OnChanges` lifecycle method but it does not trigger as expected. I have also tried calling `ChangeDetectorRef.DetectChanges` right after I change the contents of an inner array but the change detection still does not work.

Comment: Can you tell when you replace the contents of array?

Comment: @HDM91 When the view has completely rendered there's method that gets called when the scroll touched the bottom, I get more contents from backend and then replace them when the old ones.

Comment: If the child component is onPush, will only detect the change if a new instance of the lstBlockDtos is created. You are mutating the array, therefore change detection will not pick it up.

Comment: @IoannisStefanou the change detection strategy is on default mode, I haven't changed it at all.

Comment: when you change the elements of an array , still same reference pass to child component , I think if you create new array and assign it to lstBlockDtos your problem will be solved

Comment: Well, what I would do, is changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and instead of mutating the array by index, create a new array with changed data and pass it instead

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz showing your problem?

Comment: Try to use Object.assign instead `Object.assign([], yourArray, {[index]: newObject});`. There you are creating new array without mutating older. Here you have stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abfwxe

Comment: @PatrykPanek... in your stackbiltz example if we user  this.yourArray[1] = newObject then also it works fine.

Comment: @MakulSharma Yes, it will work fine in both ways, but... In my example I'm returning new array without mutating it. It means that you are creating new array reference instead of changing parts of existing one. `Inputs` in Angular fire change detection on it self when you are returning immutable data instead of mutating existing one.